# Updating a large amount of numbers

Tags: javascript, performance, websocket

From a websocket a page receives, at a high rate, a string of more than 500 numbers.
What is the most efficient way, with respect to resources, to display these numbers on the page column wise?

So far I tried two different approaches:

1. Create a static list of span elements who are updated in a for-loop using .innerHTML. The function getElementsByTagName is called in a init function at page loading in order to get the span elements in a array used in the for-loop to update them.
2. Use Jquery append() in a for-loop to append the numbers in a paragraph element, where the number has been concatenated with the tag br(eak) in order to create a column. Before the loop the function emtpy() is used to remove alle the old numbes from the paragraph.

Can this be done more efficiently? So, that the CPU load of the browser decreases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `documentFragment` (http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/)

Append all your list elements into the document fragment. This will not trigger a redraw on the document, since the fragment is not part of the DOM.

Then, remove the existing list from the DOM, and append the fragment. It's all done at once and causes only one redraw. See the linked resource for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do the append or innerHTML modifications to elements currently in the DOM inside the loop.

Create or modify an element which is not on the page, and then replace or append the new element one time. This will reduce the amount of times the page redraws and should minimize the amount of strain on the computer.